# Android app with react-native works on emulator but doesn't on physical device

Tags: android, react-native

I think title explains itself my problem, on emulator everything works as it should be, when apk builded I have transfered it on my smartphone and there's errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcYVn.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was have the same issue when i assemble Release/Debug apk and install it on my physical smartPhone

Do this commands in your Project Directory :

`mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`

(if you have the assets folder you will see error like `directory is already exist` ... no problem! go to next command)

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

`react-native run-android` or assemble the apk

it should work GOOD LUCK

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." - when I'll hit 15 reputation, for sure I'll come back and vote up, thanks again :)